oauth2 with offline refresh token
in my microservice I need to implement integration with an external REST API. The service provided me with a "long-lived" refresh token (offline-token), which I need to use to obtain an access token. The solution is fairly simple to write, but I'm wondering if there are any Spring-recommended approaches for this type of authorization?
I tried using InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository, and while I managed to use it for client_credentials type authorization:
public class DynamicReactiveClientRegistrationRepository
  implements ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository, Iterable<ClientRegistration> {

  @Getter
  private final String defaultRegistrationId;
  private final String tokenUri;
  private final Map<String, ClientRegistration> registrations;

  public DynamicReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(
    InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository registrationsRepository,
    String defaultRegistrationId
  ) {
    this.defaultRegistrationId = defaultRegistrationId;
    this.registrations = StreamSupport.stream(registrationsRepository.spliterator(), false)
      .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(ClientRegistration::getRegistrationId, Function.identity()));
    this.tokenUri = Optional.ofNullable(this.registrations.get(defaultRegistrationId))
      .map(ClientRegistration::getProviderDetails)
      .map(ClientRegistration.ProviderDetails::getTokenUri)
      .orElseThrow(() -> new DefaultClientRegistrationMissingException(defaultRegistrationId));
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<ClientRegistration> iterator() {
    return this.registrations.values().iterator();
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<ClientRegistration> findByRegistrationId(String registrationId) {
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(this.registrations.get(registrationId));
  }

  public ClientRegistration registerIfAbsent(CourierCredentials courierCredentials) {
    return this.registrations.computeIfAbsent(
      courierCredentials.clientId(),
      clientId -> ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(clientId)
        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
        .clientId(clientId)
        .clientSecret(courierCredentials.clientSecret())
        .scope("openid")
        .tokenUri(tokenUri)
        .build());
  }
}

properties:

security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      registration:
        client-name:
          authorizationGrantType: client_credentials
          clientId: id
          clientSecret: secret
          scope: openid
      provider:
        client-name:
          tokenUri: token-uri

I’m struggling to find the appropriate mechanism for authorization using a refresh token (below curl example):
curl --location 'https://url.com/auth/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=client_id' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=secret' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=refresh_token' \
--data-urlencode 'refresh_token=refresh_token'

since the ClientRegistration model does not store access tokens.
I have a sense that this is not a complicated problem and there must be good solutions available, but I can't find any useful hints that I could use.
I was able to write my custom-simply solution:

public class TokenManager {

    private final ConcurrentMap<String, AccessTokenInfo> tokenStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final APIClient client;

    public TokenManager(APIClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public Mono<String> getAccessToken(String clientId, String refreshToken) {
        return Mono.defer(() -> {
            AccessTokenInfo tokenInfo = tokenStore.get(clientId);
            if (tokenInfo == null || tokenInfo.isExpired()) {
                return client.refreshAccessToken(clientId, refreshToken)
                    .doOnNext(newTokenInfo -> tokenStore.put(clientId, newTokenInfo))
                    .map(AccessTokenInfo::accessToken);
            } else {
                return Mono.just(tokenInfo.accessToken());
            }
        });
    }

    public void clearToken(String clientId) {
        tokenStore.remove(clientId);
    }
}

but I'm wondering if there are any Spring-recommended approaches for this type of authorization
